# Initializing AVL tree in a function

Tags: c, struct, tree

I am going to create an implementation of a fan page using AVL tree (school assigment). First of all, it must have 4 functions which will be:

`void init();` for inicialization of the tree, global variables, ...

`void like(char *page, char *user);`

`void unlike(char *page, char *user);`

`char *getuser(char *page, int k);`

Implementation will be tested on some basic test which will tell me how fast is my implementation and if it works properly with many users liking, unliking and also finding a name of user liking given page by number `k` which means alphabetical order in between liked users of the page.

My question is, what should be in the `init()` function to get it working, because I don't know if it should contain only

```
void init()
{
  struct page{
        char *user;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
        int height;
  };
}
```

or something more? Because there is no `main()` function for me to implement, I can only use those 4. I am not sure where should I implement tree rotations, getting max numbers, etc... Any ideas? I am using AVL implementation from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/avl-tree-set-1-insertion/) so all of the given `struct` functions are undefined for other functions, if I create it inside `init()`. How can I achieve to make it "global"?

Comment: presumably the basic test code will call your init() function, and then some random sequence of the other 3 functions.  What do you think should happen when a user likes or unlikes a page?  Would it add nodes, remove nodes?

Comment: Yes, test code calls `init()` first. Well, since the fan page is created when the `init` is called (I think), then obviously liking page adds new user into the `page struct` and unliking removes. But I still dont know how should it be.

Comment: In addition to the four functions that are required, you can have as many global variables and additional functions as you like. (It's probably best to declare those variables and functions with the `static` keyword to limit their scope to your file.) As a minimum, you need at least one variable that points to the root of your tree.

Comment: Well then what should be in the `init` function? Cause most likely, I would put everything out of there. I can create `struct` out of the `init` and also other `struct` functions which need to be accessed from `like` and `unlike` and `getuser` functions. Right?

Comment: Yes, the `init` function is there if you need it. Nothing says you have to use it. You can leave it empty if that works for the rest of your code.

Comment: Since its there, how could I use it though? Just so I know, because it doesnt look handy to me at all.

Comment: Okay. And also, there are those two functions `like` and `unlike` both `void`. How can I insert into tree or delete, if it is void? I need to return the tree after the modification, or not? And should I take argument `*page` as my structure?

Comment: From the function prototypes that you provided, it looks to me like the `init()` function is where all of the nodes are inserted into the tree. The AVL tree must be a global data structure. The other functions may modify nodes of the tree with no need to "return the tree after the modification."

Comment: Now that I look again, there seems to be a mismatch between the function prototypes and the struct that you have in your example code. In all of the functions, `page` is a pointer to `char`. This would lead me to believe that you are passing a string to the function. But maybe you want to pass a pointer to `struct page`, where `page` is a node of the tree? In this case you don't need to return the tree because you can modify the node through the pointer.